# Session flash data doesn't persist after redirect

Tags: codeigniter

My flash data messages are not getting passed after a redirect in Codeigniter. I have a User controller:

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function register(){
        $data['title']='Register Here';
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name' , 'Name' , 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('user_name' , 'Username' , 'trim|required|max_length[32]|callback_check_username_exists'); // or is_unique[users.username]
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password','trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('confirm_password', 'Confirm Password','trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|matches[password]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Email', 'trim|required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email]', array('is_unique'=>'Email Already Used'));
        if ($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('users/register',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');  
        } else {
                  $option=array('cost'=>12);
                  $encrypt_password=password_hash($this->input->post('password'),PASSWORD_BCRYPT,$option);
                  $this->user_model->add_user($encrypt_password);
                  $this->session->set_flashdata('user_registered','You are Successfully Registered and Logged In');
                 // This works  print_r($this->session->flashdata('user_registered'));
        redirect('posts');
        }
    }
```

In the User controller flashdata 'user_registered ' is getting stored when I echo it as in comment above .

My POST controller is :

```
class Posts extends CI_Controller {  
    public function index(){
        $data['title']='Latest Posts';
        $posts=$this->post_model->get_post();
        $data['posts']=$posts;
        $this->load->view('templates/header');
        $this->load->view('posts/index',$data);
        $this->load->view('templates/footer');
}
```

My header view is :

```
<html>
        <head>
                <title>My Blog </title>
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>asset/css/bootstrap.min.css">
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url();?>asset/css/style.css">
                <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.11.1/standard/ckeditor.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="<?php echo base_url();?>">Bloggy</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarColor02" aria-controls="navbarColor02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarColor02">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php  echo base_url();?>">Home </a>
      </li>
       <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php  echo base_url();?>posts">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="<?php  echo base_url();?>category">Categories</a>
        </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php  echo base_url();?>about">About</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php  echo base_url();?>user/register">Register</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php  echo base_url();?>posts/create">Create Post</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="<?php  echo base_url();?>category/create">Create Category</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
       <div class="container">
  <!-- Flash Data --> 
  <?php if($this->session->flashdata('user_registered')): ?>
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata('user_registered');?>
   <?php else :?>
    <?php echo ' no value '; ?>
    <?php /*echo '<p class="alert alert-success">'.$this->session->flashdata('user_registered').'</p>'; */?>
   <?php endif; ?>
```

In the header view the flashdata user_registered is showing up with no value. There is only one redirect and I should be able to access the flash data.

On further investigation I found my sessions are not working at all. I have auto loaded the sessions library and in the browser I am seeing ci_session as a cookie but I tested out both userdata and flashdata are not working after redirect. Flash data should work after for one redirect as I have been doing this for a long time. My previous application which worked perfectly is also failing because sessions are not getting stored.

I created a test code like below:

```
class User extends CI_Controller {
    public function index (){
        $sex='M';
        $data1['user']=$this->user_model->get_all_users($sex);
        $this->session->set_userdata('test','data');
        $this->session->set_flashdata('flash', 'data');
        print_r($_SESSION); exit();
        redirect('projects');
    }
```

I get Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1547034241 [test] => data [flash] => data [__ci_vars] => Array ( [flash] => new ) ) .

Now I echo the session in my projects controller :

```
<?php

class Projects extends CI_Controller {

    public function index()
    {
            print_r($_SESSION); exit();
            $result= $this->project->get_projects();
            $data['result']=$result ;
            $this->load->view('pages/projects',$data);

    }
}
```

I just get this : Array ( [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1547034384 ) .

```
My config.php is $config['cookie_prefix']   = '';
$config['cookie_domain']    = '';
$config['cookie_path']      = '/';
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
$config['cookie_httponly']  = FALSE;
```

Comment: CodeIgniter supports "flashdata", or session data that will only be available for the next server request, and are then automatically cleared.

Comment: If you see my code there is only one server request that is redirect('posts') . In the posts controller I am just loading views .

Comment: I was able to fix this by upgrading to the latest version of CI . flashdata after redirect is working now . It was a bug in CI 3.0.1 . Took me one day to figure this out

Answer (score 0):

flash data is session which will available at page only.. when it get freshh request on server it empty flash dat ... i.e your redirect unset the flash data... set user_data to get your message ... and unset it when you have it like

```
$this->session->userdata('user_registered','You are Successfully Registered and Logged In');
```

unset it at view

```
<?php 
      if($this->session->userdata('user_registered')){
      echo $this->session->userdata('user_registered');
      $this->session->unset_userdata('user_registered');
      }
 ?>
```